# MATLAB if statement directly in function

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Hello everyone i'm asking a question quite stupid... Actually i'm trying to understand one's code and in a function definition, there's directly an if statement, so i'm quite confused of its meaning... thank you!

```
function [noiseuv]=Addnoise(uv,noise)
if 0
noiseuv = uv + ...;
end
if 1
noiseuv = uv + noise*randn(siwe(uv));
end
end
```

Comment: I am not a matlab expert..is it depended on value of [noiseuv]

Comment: you mean the previous noiseuv value? i tried but seems not...

Comment: `if 0` might be a certain way to keep a deprecated piece of code instead of commenting it out.

Comment: yes i think so... thx